# Math Modules Relevant Finance

Tags: education, finance

I'm a student going into my final year, my course is International Finance & Economics with a Maths Minor. I have to select 4 Maths modules for the final year but I'm having trouble selecting which ones. I want to choose the modules most relevant to Finance, and all suggestions are welcome.

Here they are;
- ANALYSIS 1 (C)
- CODAIGH & CÓRAIS DHINIMICIÚLA RÉADACHA
- EUCLIDEAN & NON-EUCLIDEAN GEOMETRY
- EXPERIMENTAL AND COMPUTATIONAL MATHEMATICS
- GRAPH THEORY
- HISTORY OF MATHEMATICS
- MATHEMATICAL BIOLOGY
- PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS
- GROUPS

If any extra clarification is needed I'm happy to provide (Oh and I'm not choosing the second module). My current choices are Analysis 1 (C), Euclidean & Non-Euclidean Geometry, Graph Theory and Groups/Partial Derivatives.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you experimental and computational mathematics because in these days computer and programming language are very important especially of you have to plot or do some manipulations on databases. Also if, for example, you have to find a general formula on datas.

Comment: See in my major I have a Advanced Financial Modelling module, it covers relevant programming, creating Financial models, the relevant maths and advanced lessons in Excel. Would experimental and computational mathematics still be as useful? (just questioning, not doubting the suggestion)

Comment: I suggested you computational science because I have seen that in this days programming language as for example F# are very common for the finance. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvoOF.png (F# in creating a financial app) and https://fsharpworks.com/workshops/finance.html. What ypou will learn in that course will give you the possibilities of doing this without have to depend from an old software as Excel.